# XSLXWriter and Angular 5, Cannot change header style in Excel file

Tags: angular

Can anyone help me with making the excel header bold? I'm using file-saver , xlsx and xlsx-style libraries to export an excel file in Angular 5 but cannot change the header style. Without xlsx-style , it works but it doesnot apply the style and  with xlsx-style, it throws errors during the serve.

```
 Dependencies are like : 
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "xlsx": "^0.13.2",
    "xlsx-style": "^0.8.13"
```

Here is file-export.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import { utils, WorkBook, WorkSheet, CellObject } from 'xlsx';
import { write } from 'xlsx-style';
const EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
       officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';


@Injectable()
export class FileExportService {

   constructor() { }

   public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    const worksheet: WorkSheet = utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    this.wrapAndCenterCell(worksheet.A1);
    const workbook: WorkBook= { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: 
    ['data'] };

   const excelBuffer: any = write(workbook, {bookType: 'xlsx', type: 
   'array'});

   this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
 }

 private wrapAndCenterCell(cell: CellObject) {
   const wrapAndCenterCellStyle = { font: {bold:true}  };
   this.setCellStyle(cell, wrapAndCenterCellStyle);
 }

 private setCellStyle(cell, style: {}) {
   cell.s = style;
 }

 private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
  const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: EXCEL_TYPE });
  FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getTime() + 
  EXCEL_EXTENSION);
}
```

}

while serving, it throws this error:

WARNING in ./node_modules/xlsx-style/xlsx.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'D:\SAP\code\test\myApp\node_
modules\xlsx-style'

ERROR in ./node_modules/xlsx-style/xlsx.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\SAP\code\test\myApp\node_modu
les\xlsx-style'
ERROR in ./node_modules/xlsx-style/ods.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\SAP\code\test\myApp\node_modu
les\xlsx-style'

Comment: facing same issue :(